# How can get a signing certificate to be detected by xcodebuild command line?

Tags: xcode, jenkins, xcode9, xcodebuild, fastlane

I am trying set up Jenkins to sign my app command line using `xcodebuild` command.

I get a `Code Signing Error` complaining:

```
Provisioning profile "XC iOS: xxxxx" doesn't include signing certificate "iPhone Distribution: Team Name (Team_ID)".
```

**Question:**
How can get my signing certificate to be detected by `xcodebuild`?

**PS:**
I am well able to sign my app using Xcode UI & selecting "*Automatically manage signing*"

Comment: Are you using fastlane, since you tagged it with `fastlane`?

Comment: I am looking for a solution which might involve `fastlane`. if `xcodebuild` cannot solve it without `fastlane`, then I need to know in this discussion

Comment: `xcodebuild` can certainly do it without `fastlane`, but using `fastlane` would be simplest